# Use custom class as key in python dictionary false hits

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, blender, porting

I am trying to implement the VBO indexer found on opengl-tutorial.org, in Python so I can export proper data directly from Blender and do not need to handle this when loading data in C++. The logic is based on a pure `memcmp` (lexicographical compare):

```c++
struct PackedVertex{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec2 uv;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    bool operator<(const PackedVertex that) const{
        return memcmp((void*)this, (void*)&that, sizeof(PackedVertex))>0;
    };
};
```

And then `PackedVertex` objects are used as keys in a `std::map`. Here is my try to implement that class in Python. I chose to use vertex id instead of position, because this is equivalent.

```Python
class VertexData:
    index=0
    normal=0
    uv=0
    def __init__(self,index,normal,uv):
        self.index=index
        self.normal=normal
        self.uv=uv
        self.uv.freeze()
        self.normal.freeze()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.index,self.normal.x,self.normal.y,self.normal.z,self.uv.x,self.uv.y))

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (self.index,self.normal.x,self.normal.y,self.normal.z,self.uv.x,self.uv.y) \
            ==(other.index,other.normal.x,other.normal.y,other.normal.z,other.uv.x,other.uv.y)

    def __ne__(self,other):
        return not(self==other)
```

Now I try to use `VertexData` as keys in a dictionary, but it claims that new keys already exists. In particular, for a *flat shaded* cube, I expect 34 unique vertices, but I only get 24. And considering the issues in comparing floating point numbers, I would expect more differences, not fewer.

I tried to use the approach to embed C++ code into the script, compile it, and launch a pipe (that worked), but I thought it would be a cleaner solution to write everything in Python.

Comment: @thebjorn Yes, it was.

Comment: the c++ code also compares `position`..

Comment: Still the same... (Vertex index is 1-1 with position)

Comment: Hmm.  the only remaining thing I can think of is that the hash-function is 'clumpy' (non-uniform) for some reason..?

Comment: @thebjorn Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Sure, just write a uniform hash function ;-)   The docs (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) suggest taking the xor of the hashes of the constituent parts. There is also the `hashlib` module (mathematically superior, but performance might be an issue).

Comment: How do you expect 34 verts for a flat shaded cube? Considering points used for uv's and normals, not shared vertices within the object data, a cube has 6 sides, with 4 verts a side that gives you 24 verts. With one level of subdivision you would get 54 points. Counting one vert and one normal for each corner makes 48. Even counting one normal and 4 verts to a face would be 30.

Comment: @sambler The UV is responsible for the remaining 10 vertices